# Django app cannot share name of folder?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Something I've had a really bad problem with in Django 2.0 is that I'll go to create an app but I want it in the folder above the project. I'm also using PyCharm 2017.1 so not sure if that's causing issues but I tend to get the same error messages if I do things in the cmd prompt too.

My working folder is called 'DjangoTest' and is empty. I'll walk you through all the steps and include the command prompt output stream.

1. Start a project:

   django-admin startproject mysite

Result:

```
DjangoTest/
 |-----> mysite/
          |-----> mysite/
          |        |-----> __init__.py
          |        |-----> settings.py
          |        |-----> urls.py
          |        |-----> wsgi.py
          |-----> manage.py
```

2. Navigate into the 'mysite' subdirectory:

   cd mysite
3. Create a subdirectory to hold the app files:

   <I created a folder named 'myapp' in the current directory>:

Folder structure now:

```
DjangoTest/
 |-----> mysite/
          |-----> myapp/
          |
          |-----> mysite/
          |        |-----> __init__.py
          |        |-----> settings.py
          |        |-----> urls.py
          |        |-----> wsgi.py
          |-----> manage.py
```

4. Create the app

   `python manage.py startapp myapp ./myapp/`

CommandError: 'myapp' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.

It seems like Django doesn't want to create the app because there is a folder there called 'myapp' but it is empty so not sure why it thinks it can't make the app there. If I don't create the folder before running the last command it complains that a directory doesn't exist. If I rename the folder to something else, it works. Can an app and the folder it's in not share the same name in Django 2.0?